# Calculate speed of an object using angle and time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, speed

I haven't had any physics class or anything close to that in a long time, and I'm currently confronted with an exercise I don't remember the formula(s) to solve it.

Assuming I have an object of unknown mass (say a wristwatch) I'm holding it using a massless string and I'm standing in a jet which is about to take off. When the jet is accelerating my object creates an angle of 25 degrees to the vertical (downwards), the entire process takes around 18 seconds. How could I calculate the speed or acceleration of the jet?

Comment: Hi. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: @Gert I thought about using movement on an angled surface, but it doesn't seem to be applicable due to the absence of the time variable and the requirement of the coefficient of friction. Apart from that, I couldn't think of any formula having any kind of angle that could work in this.

Answer (score 2):

The object will hang still at a given angle to the vertical when all of the forces are balanced so that there is no net force on the object. The only forces acting on the object are gravity ($F_g = m\mathbf{g}$), the backward force $\mathbf{F} = -m\mathbf{a}$ opposite the direction of the plane's acceleration $\mathbf{a}$ (this is a fictitious force from the frame of reference where the plane is accelerating), and the tension $\mathbf{T}$ from the string. Therefore, $\mathbf{T} + m\mathbf{g} -  m\mathbf{a}= \mathbf{0}$ is the equation that must be satisfied. You know the angles involved so you can split up the vector equation into a system of equations using the horizontal and vertical components of the forces (equal to magnitude * $\cos\theta$ and magnitude * $\sin\theta$, respectively), using the fact that both components must equal zero. There are just two unknowns (the magnitudes of $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{a}$), so you can solve for both. Once you know the acceleration, you can find the speed using the elapsed time of 18 seconds.